# how to lock horizontal scrolling when parent listbox vertical scrolling in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

My listbox contains custom templates. Every template can dragable horizontally using Toolkit GestureService.

My goal is when scrolling listbox, items cannot dragable.

I need to handle parent listbox scrolling?

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to disable the scrollbar inside a `ListBox` control like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ... >
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: My Problem is when i scrolling listbox vertically, my item moving in same time. I need lock item in this time.